# How do I configure mvc core 2 dependency injection with parameters, where one of the parameters is a dependency?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

If I have:

`public CatManager(ICatCastle catCastle, int something)`

I want to set this up to be dependency injected, but I am not sure how.

I think I can do this:

```
services.AddScoped<ICatCastle, CatCastle>();

services.AddScoped<ICatManager>(new CatManager(???, 42));
```

But I am not sure what to put in as the `???` to get the CatCastle. I'd like it to resolve a new `CatCastle` every time `CatManager` is injected.

As a further step, I wonder if it possible to do something like:

```
public CatManager(int something)

services.AddScoped<ICatManager>(new CatManager(ResolveICatCastleIntoCatCastle().SomeID));
```

So that CatManager's constructor is automatically invoked with the ID, but not the object that gets the IDs. For example, if it is a database connection I want that resolution to occur when it is created and not later on when the property is actually accessed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the factory delegate overload.

Like

```
services.AddScoped<ICatManager>(serviceProvider => 
    new CatManager(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ICatCastle>(), 42));
```

> I'd like it to resolve a new `CatCastle` every time `CatManager` is injected.

If you want a new castle then you need to register `CatCastle` with a transient scope

```
services.AddTransient<ICatCastle, CatCastle>();
```

Regarding the further step `public CatManager(int something)`, a similar approach can be done

```
services.AddScoped<ICatManager>(serviceProvider => 
    new CatManager(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ICatCastle>().SomeID));
```

where the dependency is resolved and what ever action is performed before injecting it into the dependent class.

Comment: @NibblyPig you should also look into the advice of the other answer about wrapping the constants values in a class. Makes the DI even simpler. Provided you are able to refactor the class in question.

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap the  value `42` in a component-specific configuration class and register and inject that configuration object instead.

For instance:

```
public class CatSettings
{
    public readonly int AnswerToAllCats;
    public CatSettings(int answerToAllCats) => AnswerToAllCats = answerToAllCats;
}

public class CatManager : ICatManager
{
    public CatManager(ICatCastle castle, CatSettings settings) ...
}
```

The configuration would then look like

```
services.AddScoped<ICatManager, CatManager>();
services.AddSingleton(new CatSettings(42));
```